# How to Apply llply() or lapply() to component of list produced by llply() or lapply()

Tags: r

I'm using `cl_tabulate` to get some stats on sample KDD Cup 2009 data.
Here's a sample portion of `df.trainbase`, the data I'm working with...

```
    > sample <- df.trainbase[4100:4110,220:223]
    > sample
      Var220  Var221  Var222     Var223
      4100 qcEoI0_    oslk fXLavGi LM8l689qOp
      4101 OTg4K41    oslk N9WHLT9 LM8l689qOp
      4102 54petck    oslk eEfa_vf LM8l689qOp
      4103 m_dAM23    oslk nFzwuDg LM8l689qOp
      4104 ROeipLp    zCkv K2SqEo9 LM8l689qOp
      4105 4UxGlow    oslk catzS2D LM8l689qOp
      4106 rDm6pd1    oslk Q53Rkup LM8l689qOp
      4107 XqwYlW4    oslk sMvE4Qn LM8l689qOp
      4108 EncOVQC    oslk 8AGQQMs LM8l689qOp
      4109 b0v7gqP d0EEeJi 80xXg6w LM8l689qOp
      4110 3aBfc8E    oslk aXcOEra LM8l689qOp

    > tabs <- llply(sample,cl_tabulate)
```

The tabs list looks like this (2 list elements shown):

```
    > tabs
      $Var220
       values counts
    1  qcEoI0_      1
    2  OTg4K41      1
    3  54petck      1
    4  m_dAM23      1
    5  ROeipLp      1
    6  4UxGlow      1
    7  rDm6pd1      1
    8  XqwYlW4      1
    9  EncOVQC      1
    10 b0v7gqP      1
    11 3aBfc8E      1

    $Var221
     values counts
    1    oslk      9
    2    zCkv      1
    3 d0EEeJi      1
```

I can get the number of the most prevalent level value for a specified list element (i.e., data column) like this:

```
    > max(tabs[[1]]$counts)

      [1] 37216
```

but how to get `max(tabs[[i]]$counts)` for all `i` (e.g., using `llply()` if possible)? I need the value of that most prevalent level and how many times it occurs for each column:

Ideally the final result is a simple row per variable, with variable name, most prevalent factor value, and occurrences--for Var196 as an example:

```
    Var196   1K8T    49550
```

Is it possible to hand a nested list (such as 'tabs', above) to `llply()` and point it to some element 'below' the column level of structure? I don't see it.

...and the solution (below) is to use `melt()`

```
    > m = melt(tabs, id="values")
    > m <- m[-2]
    > m

    values value     L1
    1     qcEoI0_     1 Var220
    2     OTg4K41     1 Var220
    3     54petck     1 Var220
    4     m_dAM23     1 Var220
    5     ROeipLp     1 Var220
    6     4UxGlow     1 Var220
    7     rDm6pd1     1 Var220
    8     XqwYlW4     1 Var220
    9     EncOVQC     1 Var220
    10    b0v7gqP     1 Var220
    11    3aBfc8E     1 Var220
    12       oslk     9 Var221
    13       zCkv     1 Var221
    ...
```

which is exactly what I needed.

Comment: please provide reproducible code with data. In the meantime, it looks like you could use `m = melt(tabs, id="values")` on your list, which would then be amenable to `plyr::ddply(m, "L1", summarise, max = max(value))`

Comment: Not being able to get the data and code into this comment, I added it to the original post above. In any case, melt() was the answer--thanks very much for the help.